# AttributeError: 'list' object attribute 'append' is read-only

Tags: python, python-3.x, append, error-list

I am new to this world and I am starting to take my first steps in python. I am trying to extract in a single list the indices of certain values of my list (those that are greater than 10). When using append I get the following error and I don't understand where the error is.

```py
dbs = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 23, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
       1, 1, 0, 20, 1, 1, 15, 1, 0, 0, 0, 40, 15, 0, 0]

exceed2 = []

for d, i in enumerate(dbs):
    if i > 10:
        exceed2.append= (d,i)
        print(exceed2)
```

Comment: You don't need to use a `=` to call `append`.

Comment: ```.append()``` only takes in one value. See this [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/append-extend-python/).

Comment: Also, append only takes a single argument.  If you are trying to append a tuple, you need to write `exceed2.append((d, i)).

Answer (score 3):

You probably mean to write

```
for i, d in enumerate(dbs):
    if d > 10:
        exceed2.append(i)
print(exceed2)
```

Few fixes here:

- `append=()` is invalid syntax, you should just write `append()`
- the `i, d` values from `enumerate()` are returning the values and indexes. You should be checking `d > 10`, since that's the value (per your description of the task). Then you should be putting only `i` into the `exceed2` array. (I switch the `i` and `d` variables so that `i` is for `index` as that's more conventional)
- `append(d,i)` wouldn't work anyway, as `append` takes one argument. If you want to append both the value *and* index, you should use `.append((d, i))`, which will append a tuple of both to the list.
- you probably don't want to print `exceed2` every time the condition is hit, when you could just print it once at the end.

Comment: To be pedantic, the syntax is not invalid, which is why you get a runtime error. If you had another object, e.g. `class Foo: pass` then `foo = Foo()` you could do `foo.append = (d, i)` just fine, that would assign a tuple to a `.append` attribute. But `list` objects don't allow that

Comment: It should be `if i > 10` , `d` will have the index not value.

Comment: oh true, I was just copying from the OP without thinking.

Comment: @AlexKritchevsky Then please edit your answer.

Comment: I already did. I switched the `i` and `d` variables to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to this world :D

the problem is that .append is actually a function that only takes one input, and appends this input to the very end of whatever list you provide.

Try this instead:

```
dbs = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 23, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
       1, 1, 0, 20, 1, 1, 15, 1, 0, 0, 0, 40, 15, 0, 0]

exceed2 = []

for d, i in enumerate(dbs):
    if i > 10:
        exceed2.append(i)
        print(exceed2)
```